# Does destroying a collected MELD canister decrease the amount of MELD received?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

One of my snipers managed to destroy a MELD container another operative had already opened. The Dr. Vahlen chided me for destroying MELD in that lovely way of hers, yet the UI still counts that canister as collected rather than lost. Can I freely destroy MELD canister after collecting them, or will I lose collected MELD if an open canister is destroyed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Destroying collected MELD canister does not decrease the amount of MELD awarded at the end of a mission. This conclusion is the result of a test where a collected MELD canister was destroyed on the last turn with a grenade: after 2 victories with and without destroying the canister, the amount of MELD awarded remained the same.

Comment: @spartacus thanks, after I forgot after the 2 day self-answer limit experied.